# Is it possible to use my own player in custom CAF receiver?

Tags: google-cast

I have a custom player build on Shaka Player and I would like to use it as a base for Custom CAF Chromecast Receiver.

I do it already for Receiver v2 and it works fine.

At some point in time the documentation at https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers was saying that only internal player can be used (btw. based on shaka too).

Is it possible to have custom player in CAF receiver?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I was able to use custom shaka build. But....

If you not using internal player after ~4min device will close your app. So you have to play some empty audio/video file there to prevent this.

Comment: Did you use "injected" player where you override PlayerManager methods? I think in long-run this is not a supported approach.